# Qt's slot(?) inserts redundant namespace into connect

Tags: c++, qt, signals

The problem I get is the following error message when calling connect, with MRC being the redundant namespace which I think Qt shouldn't have added - boundSubWindow isn't defined inside MRC. My understanding is the slot function isn't found, because MRC:: was prepended to it's name.

QObject::connect: No such slot MRC::boundSubWindow::myFunc(unsigned char *, int) in z:\mrc\mrc\mrc.h:23
QObject::connect:  (receiver name: 'MRCClass')

The code is

---------- mrc.h ----------

```
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>

#include "ui_MRC.h"

#include "myThread.h"
#include "boundsubwindow.h"

class MRC : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MRC(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR) : QMainWindow(parent)
    {
        ui.setupUi(this);

        m_Thread = new myThread;
        m_Subwindow = new boundSubWindow;

        connect(MRC::m_Thread, SIGNAL(mySignal(char *, int)),
                this, SLOT(boundSubWindow::myFunc(unsigned char *, int)));
    }

    static inline myThread *m_Thread;
    boundSubWindow *m_Subwindow;

private:
    Ui::MRCClass ui;
};
```

---------- boundsubwindow.h ----------

```
#include <QMdiSubWindow>

class boundSubWindow : public QMdiSubWindow
{
public:
    boundSubWindow() {}

public slots:
    void myFunc(unsigned char *, int);
};
```

---------- boundsubwindow.h ----------

```
void boundSubWindow::myFunc(unsigned char *, int) {}
```

---------- myThread.h ----------

```
#include <QThread>

class myThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    myThread() {}

signals:
    void mySignal(char *, int);
};
```

I've skipped an auto generated main.cpp for Qt GUI application, and the MRC.ui - auto generated then added a QMdiArea with Qt Creator. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and Qt 5.13

Comment: In your connect statement, replace `this` with `m_Subwindow` and you don't need the namespaces. Also, `boundSubWindow::myFunc` needs to be declared as a slot in your class for the old connect syntax to work.

Comment: @thuga - made the two changes you've suggested, and now I get "QObject::connect: No such slot MRC::this->myFunc(unsigned char *, int) in z:\mrc\mrc\mrc.h:2"

Comment: Shouldn't it be `connect(m_Thread, SIGNAL(mySignal(char *, int)), m_Subwindow, SLOT(myFunc(unsigned char *, int)));` instead? And you must declare `myFunc()` as a slot in `boundSubWindow` class.

Comment: @UriRaz I don't know what you did, but your connect statement should look like in vahancho's comment.

Comment: Fixed the original post (and code, of course) to put myFunc in slots. Copied & pasted vahancho's connect statement, and now I get the following error message: QObject::connect: No such slot QMdiSubWindow::myFunc(unsigned char *, int) in z:\mrc\mrc\mrc.h:23

Comment: Did you declare `m_Subwindow` as `QMdiSubWindow` instead of `boundSubWindow`?

Comment: @thuga m_Subwindow is defined as boundSubWindow*, five lines from the bottom of mrc.h

Comment: `boundSubWindow` class is missing the `Q_OBJECT` macro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
connect(MRC::m_Thread, SIGNAL(mySignal(char *, int)),
            this, SLOT(boundSubWindow::myFunc(unsigned char *, int)));
```

`boundSubWindow::myFunc` is not slot of `this`. Also, specifying the namespace for m_Thread member variable seems quite redundant. You probably want this:

```
connect(m_Thread,    SIGNAL(mySignal(char *, int)),
        m_subWindow, SLOT(myFunc(unsigned char *, int)));
```

Additionally, add `Q_OBJECT` macro to `boundSubWindw` class and re-run *qmake* explicitly (you have to do that when adding these Qt macros to files which didn't previously have them).

---

Also, you should use the new connect syntax so you get compile time errors instead of run time errors:

```
connect(m_Thread,    &myThread::mySignal,
        m_subWindow, &boundSubWindow::myFunc);
```

---

Finally, it's common Qt convention to have class names start with capital, so consider renaming to `BoundSubWindow` and `MyThread`, if you want other Qt programmers to be able to easily read your code.